# Picasso can't load image inside StorageReference's onSuccess method

Tags: java, android, firebase, picasso, firebase-storage

When trying Picasso on the runtime `onStart()` method it normally loads the image from Firebase using the download link from the console.

But when I try to load an image inside StorageReference `onSuccess` method it just won't work.

This class is extending Fragment:

```
@Override
public void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
    super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);

    if (requestCode == GALLERY_IN && resultCode == Activity.RESULT_OK) {
        isGranted = true;
        String path = FireStorage.retUID() + "/";
        showIndProgress();
        Uri uri = data.getData();

        StorageReference childPathRef = FireStorage.storageRef.child(path + uri.getLastPathSegment());
        childPathRef.putFile(uri)
                .addOnCompleteListener(new OnCompleteListener<UploadTask.TaskSnapshot>() {
                    @Override
                    public void onComplete(@NonNull Task<UploadTask.TaskSnapshot> task) {
                        if(task.isSuccessful()) {
                            Picasso.with(mContext).load(task.getResult().getDownloadUrl())
                                    .into(profView);

                            Picasso.Builder build = new Picasso.Builder(mContext);
                            build.listener(new Picasso.Listener() {
                                @Override
                                public void onImageLoadFailed(Picasso picasso, Uri uri, Exception exception) {
                                    Toast.makeText(mContext, "exception\n" + exception.toString(), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

                                }
                            });
                            progressDialog.dismiss();
                        } else {
                            //failed
                        }

                    }
                });

    }

}
```

This is my FirebaseStorage instance on another Class:

```
public static FirebaseStorage storage = FirebaseStorage.getInstance();
public static StorageReference storageRef = 
                           storage.getReferenceFromUrl("gs://myurl.appspot.com/");
```

Manifest:

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET"/>
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE"/>
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
```

My XML layout:

```
<RelativeLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="200dp"
    android:background="@drawable/gcover"
    android:id="@+id/relativeLayout">

    <de.hdodenhof.circleimageview.CircleImageView xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
        android:id="@+id/profPhoto"
        android:clickable="true"
        android:layout_width="120dp"
        android:layout_height="120dp"
        android:padding="20dp"
        android:src="@drawable/default_prof"
        android:scaleType="centerCrop"
        app:civ_border_color="@color/trans"
        app:civ_border_width="2dp"
        android:layout_centerVertical="true"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true" />

</RelativeLayout>
```

My views initialization:

```
@Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater,
                         ViewGroup container,
                         Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_prof, container, false);
    profView = (CircleImageView) view.findViewById(R.id.profPhoto);

    btn1 = (Button) view.findViewById(R.id.btn_1);
    btn2 = (Button) view.findViewById(R.id.btn_2);
    btn3 = (Button) view.findViewById(R.id.btn_3);
    return view;
}
```

Comment: I had similar issue with Picasso check out profView from  line: Picasso.with(mContext).load(task.getResult().getDownloadUrl())
                                    .into(profView);

profView can be recreated with Fragment and Picasso request is finished.

Comment: @Wrobel Can you please share your code or post it on the answers below if you resolved the same problem?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I just switched from **CircleImageView** to a normal **ImageView** and it suddenly worked.

Answer (score 9):

**Update 2:**

While the code I posted works for me, you indicate that it fails for you.  My test does not use a fragment, I don't know what version of the libraries you are using, it's now known how the fragment is being added to the layout, etc.  There are too many possible causes of the different behavior to effectively debug it on SO.

As an experiment, you can try using Glide and FirebaseUI to perform the download instead of Picasso.  The code is shown below and works for me.  Because the download is from the storage reference and not the URL, this approach requires read access to the storage.  You also need to add these lines to your build dependencies:

```
// FirebaseUI 2.0.1 is the version to use for Firebase SDK version 11.0.1
// SDK/Firebase version compatibility is important.
// See the FirebaseUI docs for a table of compatible versions.
compile 'com.firebaseui:firebase-ui-storage:2.0.1'
compile 'com.github.bumptech.glide:glide:3.8.0'
```

.

```
childPathRef.putFile(Uri.fromFile(file))
    .addOnCompleteListener(new OnCompleteListener<UploadTask.TaskSnapshot>() {
        @Override
        public void onComplete(@NonNull Task<UploadTask.TaskSnapshot> task) {
            if (task.isSuccessful()) {
                Log.d(TAG, "Upload: SUCCESS");

                Glide.with(mContext)
                    .using(new FirebaseImageLoader())
                    .load(childPathRef)
                    .dontAnimate()
                    .listener(new RequestListener<StorageReference, GlideDrawable>() {
                        @Override
                        public boolean onException(Exception e, StorageReference model,
                               Target<GlideDrawable> target, boolean isFirstResource) {
                            Log.e(TAG, "Download: FAILED: ", e);
                            return false;
                        }
                        @Override
                        public boolean onResourceReady(GlideDrawable resource,
                               StorageReference model, Target<GlideDrawable> target,
                               boolean isFromMemoryCache, boolean isFirstResource) {
                            Log.d(TAG, "Download: SUCCESS");
                            return false;
                        }
                    })
                    .into(mCircleImageView);
            } else {
                Log.e(TAG, "Upload: FAILED: " + task.getException().getMessage());
            }
        }
    });
```

**Update:**

Additional debugging showed that the upload and download were both completing sucessfully.  The problem was with the rendering of the downloaded image.  The [documentation for CircleImageView](https://github.com/hdodenhof/CircleImageView) indicates that `noFade()` must be used when downloading from Picasso:

> If you use an image loading library like Picasso or Glide, you need to
>   disable their fade animations to avoid messed up images. For Picasso
>   use the `noFade()` option, for Glide use `dontAnimate()`.

It was also found that small images were rendered but large images were displayed as black. `fit()` was added to cause Picasso to resize the image.

---

To detect both upload success and failure, use a [completion listener](https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/admin/java/reference/com/google/firebase/tasks/OnCompleteListener) instead of just a success listener, and test `task.isSuccessful()`.  The upload is probably failing because of security rules, or invalid `StorageReference`:

```
StorageReference childPathRef = Class.storageRef.child(path + uri.getLastPathSegment());
childPathRef.putFile(uri).addOnCompleteListener(new OnCompleteListener<UploadTask.TaskSnapshot>() {
    @Override
    public void onComplete(@NonNull Task<UploadTask.TaskSnapshot> task) {
        if (task.isSuccessful()) {
            Log.d(TAG, "Upload: SUCCESS");
            Picasso.with(mContext)
                .load(task.getResult().getDownloadUrl())
                .noFade()
                .fit()
                .into(profView, new Callback() {
                    @Override
                    public void onSuccess() {
                        Log.d(TAG, "Download: SUCCESS");
                        Toast.makeText(mContext, "download done" , Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();                        }

                    @Override
                    public void onError() {
                        Log.d(TAG, "Download: FAILED");
                    }
                });
            Toast.makeText(mContext, "upload done" , Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        } else {
            Log.e(TAG, "Upload: FAILED: " + task.getException().getMessage());
        }
        progressDialog.dismiss();
    }
});
```

Comment: Hi Bob thanks for your answer, unfortunately the image is still not showing but i can assure you that the image is successfully uploaded as i can see it in the Firebase storage.

Comment: Strange.  The code works for me when I download to an ImageView.

Comment: This class is extending Fragment, maybe it has something to do with lifecycles? I literally have no idea.

Comment: @HUSTLE What log messages or toasts and you seeing?  Is the completion listener running?

Comment: Yes the toast inside completion listener is running. and visited the link through logs and it is fine.

Comment: @HUSTLE:  Do I understand correctly that you see log output or toasts that make you _certain_ that:  `task.isSuccessful()==true` and `onImageLoadFailed()` does **not** run?  When you invoke download from `onStart()`, are you downloading to the same view, `profView`?  When download fails, do you see anything in `profView`?

Comment: @HUSTLE: I updated my answer to add a callback to the download request.  I think the listener code you have is ineffective because it is creating a different Picasso instance than the one used for the download.

Comment: yes i am sure i instantiated and referenced my ImageView correctly, I updated my post with XML code and Manifest file i tried your updated code but it is still not working.

Comment: Does the "download done" toast appear?  Anything noteworthy in the debug log output?

Comment: It does appear, It feels like the method is ignoring the Picasso line

Comment: I found this [post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20034875/android-picasso-not-loading-in-fragment) but how do i transfer the image when `onBitmapLoaded()` is called?

Comment: @HUSTLE: I updated my answer to include `.noFade()` and `.fit()`.  These worked for me.  I'll add explanation shortly.

Comment: Hi Bob, i appreciate your effort but it is still not working.

Comment: @HUSTLE Can you post the (very) long URL for the image you are trying to display?  If your not comfortable doing that, what is the image size and type (jpf, gif, etc).

Comment: That displays okay for me.  Investigating the remaining possible causes would require seeing more of your code and is difficult to do with comments and posts.  I'll take a break.  Hopefully someone else can help.

Comment: @HUSTLE:  You indicate `profView` is in a fragment.  Can you post the  fragment code the defines and initializes `profView`.  I presume you initialize  `profView` in `onCreateView()`.  If that method is not too large, can you post all of it?  Do you see any indications that the fragment view is correctly created and added to the layout?  In other words, do you see other elements of the fragment view or the placeholder for `profView`.

Comment: It still not working, But i came up with my own solution saving the URL in a SharedPreference then when the `onStart()` triggers back it normally loads the image but it is not actually very efficient and reliable. Any suggestions?

Comment: @PERSISTENCE: I'm willing to look at this more.  Having already tried the simple fixes with no improvement, I don't see how anyone will be able to fully understand the problem without seeing your build file and more (maybe all) of the related code.  To get a solution, you may need to make your project public on Github or some other code sharing site.  It's understandable if for privacy or proprietary reasons you don't can't do that, but it may be the only way forward.

Answer (score 2):

Limitations for [de.hdodenhof.circleimageview.CircleImageView](https://github.com/hdodenhof/CircleImageView#limitations)

- The ScaleType is always CENTER_CROP and you'll get an exception if you try to change it. This is (currently) by design as it's perfectly fine for profile images.
- Enabling adjustViewBounds is not supported as this requires an unsupported ScaleType
- **If you use an image loading library like Picasso or Glide, you need to disable their fade animations to avoid messed up images. For Picasso use the noFade() option, for Glide use dontAnimate(). If you want to keep the fadeIn animation, you have to fetch the image into a Target and apply a custom animation yourself when receiving the Bitmap.**
- Using a TransitionDrawable with CircleImageView doesn't work properly and leads to messed up images.

Answer (score 1):

It is possible that in this line of code:

```
     Picasso.with(mContext).load(task.getResult().getDownloadUrl())
                                .into(profView);
```

profView is recreating with fragment, and `Picasso.into(View view)` keeps week reference to view.

From docs:

> public void into(android.widget.ImageView target) Asynchronously
>   fulfills the request into the specified ImageView.  Note: This method
>   keeps a weak reference to the ImageView instance and will
>   automatically support object recycling.

Try to use:

```
public void into(@NotNull ImageView target,
             Callback callback)
```

Comment: It says annotations not allowed.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe it's a conflict with the `CircleImageView`.

Try to change it with an ImageView or define the `CircleImageView` like an `ImageView`.

**Try :**

```
ImageView profView = (ImageView) view.findViewById(R.id.profPhoto);
```