# glide with firebase not loading picture

Tags: android, firebase, firebase-storage, android-glide

My image wont load when using firebase-glide. I tried several things, including: changing firebase storage version, changing the circle image view to an actual imageview and using a fix filepath for the file.

imageview:

```
 <de.hdodenhof.circleimageview.CircleImageView
            android:id="@+id/Profilepicture"
        android:layout_margin="10dp"
        android:layout_width="150dp"
        android:layout_height="150dp"
       />
```

Glide:

```
Profilepicture = (ImageView) rootView.findViewById(R.id.Profilepicture);
        FirebaseUser user = FirebaseAuth.getInstance().getCurrentUser();

        if (user != null) {
            Userid = user.getUid();
            profilepictureRef = mStorageRef.child("images/"+ Userid);
            Glide.with(this)
                    .using(new FirebaseImageLoader())
                    .load(profilepictureRef)
                    .into(Profilepicture);

        } else {
            // No user is signed in
        }
```

Build.gradle (app module)

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'
apply plugin: 'android-apt'
android {
    compileSdkVersion 26
    buildToolsVersion '25.0.2'

    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "com.example.sanchez.testproject"
        minSdkVersion 21
        targetSdkVersion 26
        multiDexEnabled true
        versionCode 0
        versionName "0"
    }
    buildTypes {
        release {
            minifyEnabled false
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
        }
        debug {
            debuggable true
        }
    }
}



dependencies {

    compile fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
    compile 'com.android.support:design:25.3.1'
    compile 'com.github.bumptech.glide:glide:3.8.0'
    compile 'com.firebaseui:firebase-ui-storage:2.0.1'
    compile 'com.android.support:design:25.3.1'
    compile 'com.google.firebase:firebase-auth:10.2.4'
    compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-auth:10.2.4'
    compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:25.3.1'
    compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services:10.2.4'
    compile 'com.android.support:cardview-v7:25.3.1'
    compile 'com.android.support:recyclerview-v7:25.3.1'
    compile 'com.jakewharton:butterknife:8.1.0'
    compile 'com.squareup.picasso:picasso:2.5.2'
    compile 'com.android.support:multidex:1.0.1'
    compile 'pl.droidsonroids.gif:android-gif-drawable:1.2.6'
    compile 'de.hdodenhof:circleimageview:2.1.0'
    compile 'com.android.support:support-v4:25.3.1'
    compile 'com.android.support:exifinterface:25.3.1'
    compile 'com.google.firebase:firebase-storage:10.2.4'
    compile 'com.google.firebase:firebase-database:10.0.1'
    testCompile 'junit:junit:4.12'
    apt 'com.jakewharton:butterknife-compiler:8.1.0'
}

apply plugin: 'com.google.gms.google-services'
```

Maybe some of theese dependencies don't fit together.

What can I try to solve this problem?

Comment: why you use `FirebaseImageLoader`

Comment: it says so in the firebase documentation

Comment: i use firebase at app but does't load custom downloaded

Comment: Try adding `dontAnimate()` to your Glide request as shown in "Update 2" of this answer: https://stackoverflow.com/a/44608682/4815718.  Adding a completion listener to your request (see same linked answer) will also give you more debug info.

Comment: When attaching the error listener i get this error: "java.io.IOException: Could not open resulting stream". I've seen this error in several other questions, but i've already tried to change the firebase-storage version, without any success.

Comment: Post your app module build.gradle so we can see what versions of the libraries you are using.

Comment: The only thing I have specified is: compile 'com.firebaseui:firebase-ui-storage:1.2.0' and compile 'com.github.bumptech.glide:glide:3.7.0'

Comment: Have you tried 2.0.1. and 3.8.0?

Comment: Yes, but everytime I want to start the app it throws me this error: "cannot access zzbti".

Comment: Check your logcat for `W/GooglePlayServicesUtil: Google Play services out of date`.  Your device/emulator may have on old version of Google Play services.

Comment: my device is on the newest version of google play services.

Comment: It would be helpful if you posted your build.gradle.  You only listed two dependencies, but you must also have some support libs, right?

Comment: I posted the whole build.gradle in the question

Comment: All `firebase` and `play-services` libs must use the same version.There are also version compatibility requirements for FirebaseUI [explained here](https://github.com/firebase/FirebaseUI-Android#dependencies) for Firebase  and Support libraries.  With all the modules you are using, it may be a challenge to make all the transitive dependencies compatible.  Do you really need both Glide and Picasso?

Comment: I updated all dependencies and it seems to be working, thanks alot!